# R markdowns error while using render to pdf: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:

Tags: r, r-markdown, render

I am having problems when I run the following code:

```
for (i in as.vector(unidades$Unid_Fed)){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "file.path/MR.Rmd",
                      output_format = "pdf_document",
                      output_file = paste("Texto_",i, Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep='_'),
                      output_dir = "file.path/Multi_reports")}
---
```

and the MR.Rmd is:

```
---
title: "multiple pdf reports with special character ç í ã"
author: ''
date: ''
header-includes: 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{28pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{ibge.png}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{ibge.png}\\[\bigskipamount]}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

output: pdf_document
---
##  Text - First part 
\begingroup\Huge
\begin{center}
Other text using special characters like Ç í ã... 
\end{center}
\endgroup
```

When I run this, I have output problems like this:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Â­ not set up for use with LaTeX.

Error: Failed to compile D:/Users/...

Comment: Did you save the file as UTF-8? If not, go to file > save with encoding > utf-8.

Comment: Hi, yes, I use UTF-8 as standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered: I just need to use encoding="UTF-8" in render:

```
for (i in as.vector(unidades$Unid_Fed)){
rmarkdown::render(input = "file.path/MR.Rmd",
                  output_format = "pdf_document",
                  output_file = paste("Texto_",i, Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep='_'),
                  output_dir = "file.path/Multi_reports",
                  encoding="UTF-8")}
---
```